# Does not taken variable from jquery to ajax

Tags: ajax

I assigned id value for jquery variable but it does not taken to ajax from jquery. How to find correct solution,

Here my code,

```
$(function(){
        $('.delme').click(function(){
           /* if($('#pwd').val() == 'admin'){

            }else{
              alert('failure');
            }*/

 var del_id= $('.del').attr('id');           //var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();


            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'delete1.php',
                data:{'del_id':del_id},
            success: function(data){

                 if(data==0){
                    $ele.fadeOut().remove();
                    alert("Successfully deleted");
                 }else if(data==1){
                        alert("can't delete the row")
                 }
             }

            });
        });
    });
      </script>
```

Comment: You sure that your $('.del').attr('id');  is fetching data to your del_id variable. You can console.log to check the output.

Comment: i got it now i have another one issue how to close bootstrap modal class using jquery

Comment: $('#modalwindow').modal('hide'); will hide your modal.

Comment: great man it's working thank you